I am having difficulty with the adding the additional Step 6 to the Ken Flerlage Sankey funnel template
I have used all the tips and tricks I could find on the Tableau community. Thank you Ken Flerlage for providing such great instructions, however I'm having a bit of a challenge still. As you can see my Curve pill is green and all of the nested calculations are set up as per your instructions under a different but related question.

However the width of the lines are too wide and they don't match up with my Step 5 and Step 6 bars. Even as I fixed the size of the y-axis the bottom bar seems to disappear a bit from view.
The only thing I can think of is when I look at the nested calculations there are some there for Step 4. I'm not sure how they got in there, but any idea on how to remove them?

This is the current stage of the funnel.


Starting with version 2024.2, there are much easier ways to make Sankey (and other complex) chart types in Tableau using viz extensions. See the viz extensions listed on the Tableau Exchange
Some of the extensions require a purchase, but Tableau did provide a free Sankey viz extension.
I'm not saying that that there is no reason to ever build sankey diagrams the "hard way" now. Perhaps you need some additional control or something. But for most purposes, using the free viz extension will be alot easier and more robust.
The approach the Flerlage brothers and others describe can work, but is pretty cumbersome and brittle. That's not a criticism of them. Very clever people like the Flerlage brothers figured out ways to carefully combine several Tableau features to make Tableau do something it wasn't originally designed to do. If you learn the details of how those approaches work, you'll learn alot of valuable info that will be useful down the road. But if you want to make Sankey diagram easily in a way that doesn't break when something changes in your dataset structure, then try the new viz extensions first.
